# Why Won't My Button Be Displayed??

Tags: python, button, tkinter

```
#Last one Looses (II)
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#window
root.title("Last one Looses Mark II")

#Counters Entry
counters = StringVar()
countersL = Label(root, text = "How many counters do you want to play with (10-50)")
countersL.pack(side = LEFT)
countersE = Entry(root, textvariable = counters, bd = 5)
countersE.pack(side = RIGHT)
#Function to process this
def countersinput():
    no_counters = int(input(counters.get()))
no_counters = int(input(counters.get()))
#Submit Button
countersB = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = countersinput)
countersB.pack(side = BOTTOM)
#Making sure the counters are between 10-50
while no_counters > 50 or no_counters < 10:
    Error = Message(root, text="You need to pick between 10 and 50 counters...")
    Error.pack()
    counters = StringVar()
    countersL = Label(root, text = "How many counters do you want to play with (10-50)")
    countersL.pack(side = LEFT)
    countersE = Entry(root, textvariable = counters, bd = 5)
    countersE.pack(side = RIGHT)
    def countersinput():
        no_counters = int(input(counters.get()))
    countersB = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = countersinput)
    countersB.pack(side = BOTTOM)

#Sucess Message
Sucess = Message(root, text=("You are playing with",no_counters,"counters"))

root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I run it in IDLE the tkinter window does not come up and when I run it into the command line (python one...) it displays the window but with no "submit" button.

I'm really confused please help!

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you realize that your GUI program is asking for input from the command line, and that you're doing that *before* creating the submit button? That's the reason why the submit button is not showing up. If you're writing a GUI program, you should not be trying to read input from the command line.

If you enter a number between 10 and 50 from the terminal, your code should display a window. However, if you enter a number outside that range, nothing will ever show because of the `while no_counters ...` loop. That loop will run infinitely, preventing any other interaction with the GUI, and preventing any other widgets from showing up.

Comment: Right, i'm a bit confused can you clarify what you mean

Comment: @user3262355: clarify what part. Do you not understand what I mean by "asking for input from the command l ine"? Or do you not understand why the while loop is infinite? Do you understand what an event loop is how why it is necessary?

Comment: Ok, right instead of the while loop what should I have put... and how do i ask for an input and use the answer in the rest of the program... all in tkinter :)